# HTML: Need innerHTML to become on it's parent z-index

Tags: html, z-index

I got a button which is inside a div, but I need to get that div on top of this button, in order to be able to use onMouseOut event.

I tried to change z-indexes of those two, though that didn't helped. Any ideas? I can include code for better understanding but I think it's not necessary.

Comment: I think your approach is flawed. Putting the div on top of the button will effectively disable the button. What's the root problem?

Comment: The problem is that when I disable the button with javascript it can't react to onMouseMove event, so I have to use a div on it in order to get that javascript function going.

Comment: jquery parent() http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Comment: But why do you need `mouseMove`? In a mobile world full of touch devices, that's probably not a good thing to use anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Impossible. Children will always appear above their parent.

You need to seek another approach; disabled elements do not appear to have events. I'd reconsider the UI to circumvent this issue. If you absolutely must have this functionality, perhaps replace the disabled button with another HTML element that can accept mouse over events.

http://jsfiddle.net/4HU72/

HTML

```
<button>Active Button</button>
<div>Disabled Button</div>
<a href="#">Disable button</a>
<span></span>
```

CSS

```
button, div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #336699;
}

div {
    display: none;
}
```

Javascript

```
$("a").click(function() {
   $("button").hide();
   $("div").show();
});

$("button, div").mousemove(function(e) {
    $("span").html(e.pageX+"|"+e.pageY);
});
```